# Progmatically recreating Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to recreate a Kafka topic grammatically.
I am using `kafka.admin.AdminUtils` for the same.

Here is my rought code:

```
 AdminUtils.deleteTopic(zkUtils, topicName);
 AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtils, topicName, partitions, replicationFactor, new Properties());
```

Above code is working most of the time, however several times it fails with following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" kafka.common.TopicExistsException: Topic "new_topic" already exists.
        at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createOrUpdateTopicPartitionAssignmentPathInZK(AdminUtils.scala:253)
        at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala:237)
        at kafka.admin.AdminUtils.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala)
```

What I understand is that topic is not getting deleted properly. What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot invoke createTopic right after invoking deletingTopic. Two things must be taken care of:

1. Set 'delete.topic.enable' to true
2. Since deleting topic is an asynchronous operation, you'd better make sure all metadata has been deleted successfully from within Zookeeper before creating a new topic

Comment: I have already set delete.topic.enable to true. In order to achieve point 2, is there any call back that from kafka which notifies when delete operation is completed successfully?

Comment: Seems no out-of-box callback function can be used. A possible way is to monitor the existence for zk node '/admin/delete_topics/<topic>'. Removing this zk node is the last but one step during deleting a topic, which occurs before clearing controller caches that is not easy to be monitored.